# How to install this add on from GitHub on Plex

Tags: github, plex

I am trying to install this add on for Plex TV. I am not sure how to install.

Can someone please help.

Thanks

```
https://github.com/Moussekateer/Transmogrify-for-Plex-chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is a chrome extension, it would be easier to install it through a chrome brwser, by accessing the chrome web store at:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/transmogrify-for-plex/jdogfefgaagaledbkgeffgbjlaaplpgo

That way, you just have to click the "install" button.

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't give me all the listed features just stats.

Answer (score 0):

You can easly install git plugins for plex if you install plex webtools.

Within plexwebtools you can just drop the git link and it will automaticly download and install your new plugin.

https://forums.plex.tv/t/rel-webtools-unsupported-appstore/206843